# DownPicker when selected how to get the Array Index Value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uipickerview

I have followed this [link](https://www.ryadel.com/en/downpicker-drop-down-list-combobox-for-ios-in-objective-c/#Installing_as_Control_Wrapper_recommended) to install the DownPicker. I need to get the NSMutableArray index value when the item is selected. The reason behind is I have 2 array. One is for country and one is for code. When user pick the country, I need to get the index value to get the code. Any help is gladly appreciated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //=== Initiallize the Mutable Array
    countryMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    codeMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //=== Initialize the responseData Mutable Data
    self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];

    //=== Pass the string to web and get the return Country response.write
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    sURL = appDelegate.gURL;
    sURL = [sURL stringByAppendingString:@"/apps/getcountry.asp?"];

    NSURLRequest *requestCountry = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sURL]];

    (void) [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestCountry delegate:self];

    //=== Pass the string to web and get the return Code response.write
    sURL = appDelegate.gURL;
    sURL = [sURL stringByAppendingString:@"/apps/getctcode.asp?"];

    NSURLRequest *requestCode = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sURL]];

    (void) [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestCode delegate:self];

    self.pickerCountry = [[DownPicker alloc] initWithTextField:self.txtCountry withData:countryMArray];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` add a target to  `pickerCountry`

```
 [self.pickerCountry addTarget:self 
  action:@selector(pickerClicked:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

//

```
-(void)pickerClicked:(id)dp {

     NSString* selectedValue = [self.pickerCountry text];

       for ( int i = 0 ; i < countryMArray.count; i++) {

         NSString*item = [countryMArray objectAtIndex:i];

         if([item isEqualToString:selectedValue])
         {
             [self.pickerCode selectRow:i inComponent:0 animated:YES];

             break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When user scrolls, then add the target. You will get the callback in your desired method as follows:

```
[self.pickerCountry addTarget:self 
    action:@selector(dp_Selected:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


-(void)dp_Selected:(id)dp {
    NSString* selectedValue = [self.pickerCountry text];
    // do what you want
    //search the text to get index value
}
```

Official link:
https://github.com/Darkseal/DownPicker#status-change-event-handling